# Prove that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Prove that if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ are both real numbers, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$.

**Attempt**

Intuitively this makes sense to me. Take $y = x$. This slope is constant but it increases arbitrarily, and it seems that we can't make both the slope and value of $f(x)$ to be real numbers without "flattening" out the graph. I tried first saying $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = a$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = b$. Then we might be able to do something with the L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, then clearly

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+{f(x)\over x}\right)=1$$

But ${x+f(x)\over x}$ qualifies for L'Hopitation, which gives

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left({x+f(x)\over x}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left({1+f'(x)\over 1}\right)=1+\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$$

Hence $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$.

Comment: This is under assumption that $f(x)$ is a differentiable function on some open interval right? What if $f(x)$ is not differentiable?

Comment: @user19405892: Is $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)$ meaningful if $f$ fails to be differentiable for all sufficiently large $x$?

Comment: @user19405892, the assumption that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists implies that $f'(x)$ is defined for all sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: @Bungo, great minds think alike....

Comment: @BarryCipra :-) Nice answer, btw (+1)

Comment: No need for l'hopital, elementary proof below.

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle f(n+1)-f(n)=\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{n+1-n}=f'(c_n)$ where $c_n\in (n,n+1)$

Letting $n\to \infty$, $$0=\lim_\infty f'$$

Comment: How exactly does this arrive at the result? Do you assume continuity of f'? Is lim_n c_n = lim_n n?

Comment: @BCLC No, I'm simply using the fact that $\lim_\infty f'$ exist. That implies $\lim_n f'(c_n)=\lim_x f'(x)$

Comment: LeGrandDODOM, how do you know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} f'(c_n) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$? Oh, is it true for the similar reasons that reason that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f'(n) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists is true? Or does it follow from the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f'(n) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists?

Comment: @BCLC For the same reason that $\lim_n f(n)$ exists when $\lim_x f(x)$ exists

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f(x)-f(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^x f'(t)\,dt$, especially for some $x_0$ *sufficiently large* and $x\ge x_0$.

Comment: Does your proof assume $$\int_{x_0}^{\infty} f'(t) dt$$ exists?

Comment: @BCLC No, I think. It just uses the fact that $f'(t)> \frac b2$ for large $t$ if, say, $b>0$.

Comment: @BCLC For the little it's worth, the hypothesis guarantees the existence of the improper Riemann integral even when $f'\cdot 1_{[0,\infty)}\notin L^1$.

Answer (score 1):

I like Barry Cipra's answer. Here's another proof along the same lines:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty} {x f(x) \over x} 
= \lim_{x\to \infty} {x f'(x) + f(x) \over 1} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \big(x f'(x) + f(x)\big)
$$
Now if $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)>0$, $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= +\infty$, 
and if $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)<0$, $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$, 
both of which violate an assumption; hence $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Do you assume $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf(x) = \infty$ ?

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf'(x) = 0$, need we have that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$?

Comment: @BCLC : If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L$ is positive, then for large values of $x$, $f(x) > L/2$. Thus, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} x f(x) \ge \lim_{x\to \infty} x \cdot L/2 = \infty$. Same logic if $L<0$.

Comment: @BCLC [second comment]: Remember that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ is a real number, so it's either positive, negative or zero. If it was positive, then we would have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} xf'(x)=\infty$; if it were negative, we would have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} xf'(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. Also, did you mean f' instead of f in the last part?

Answer (score 0):

Employing the Mean value theorem, entails that,  for each $x$ there exists $c_x\in (x,x+1)$ such that

$$f'(c_x)=f(x+1)-f(x)\to0$$

Hence $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(c_x) =0$ since, $c_x\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ we have