# Prove that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f^{n}(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Assume $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f^{(n)}(x)$ are both real numbers. Prove that $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f^{n}(x) = 0$$

We have that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)+x^n}{x^n} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)+nx^{n-1}}{nx^{n-1}} = \cdots = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x)+n!}{n!} = \lim_{x \to \infty}f^{(n+1)}(x) = 1,$$ by L'Hospital's rule. But did I make a mistake or how does this show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f^{n}(x) = 0$?

Comment: That doesn't prove anything - L'Hopital's rule doesn't even apply here, since you don't know $f(x) \to 0$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is a real number implies that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^n} = 0$, so L'Hospital's rule does apply.

Comment: Nope, the condition for L'hopital is that the top and bottom tend to zero (or, equivalently, infinity). That might not be true.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood We have an infinite limit here though. Also I never assumed $f(x) \to 0$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood What I am saying is this $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) + x^n) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^n = \infty$. Thus we may use L'Hospitals.

Comment: You can easily modify what you started with. Replace $f(x)/x^n$ with $n!f(x)/x^n$. I agree that the first numerator tends to infinity. Having $f(x)\to r$, for $x$ sufficiently large, $0\le x^n-|r| \le |x^n+f(x)|$

Comment: You need to justify $|f'(x)+nx^{n-1}|\to\infty$ though

Comment: I have taken the freedom to clean-up your code a little, the line with formulae was so long that it dodn't display properly. Also, the parantheses were not needed.

Comment: The last equality appearts to be an error because L'Hopital doesn't apply.

Comment: (Almost) duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705034/prove-that-displaystyle-lim-x-to-infty-fx-0?rq=1).

Comment: see related question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/730411/72031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously as $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ exists we have$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)+x^n}{x^n} =1$$
So your 2nd from last inequality is patently incorrect. You can't use L'Hospital's rule because you no longer have an indeterminate form. This is no issue though, as just equate your 3rd last step with your 1st. $$1=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x)+n!}{n!}$$ so obviously from this $$1+\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}=1$$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the following version of L'Hopital is not as well known as the version stated for $\infty/\infty:$ Suppose $f,g$ are differentiable on some $(a,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = \infty.$ If $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)/g'(x) =L,$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)/g(x) =L.$

This is the continuous version of its well known cousin, the Stolz-Cesaro theorem.

In the problem at hand, let $L = \lim f(x),M = \lim f^{(n)}(x) = M.$ Apply the above version of L'Hopital to get

$$\lim \frac{f(x)}{x^n} = \lim \frac{f'(x)}{nx^{n-1}} = \cdots = \lim \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!} =\frac{M}{n!}.$$

Because $f(x) \to L,$ the limit of $f(x)/x^n$ is clearly $0.$ It follows that $M=0.$

Comment: How do we know that $f'(x), f''(x),... $ are all differentiable? They may be differentiable nowhere.

Comment: You are assuming $f^{(n)}$ exists everywhere, right?

Comment: For some $n$ we are.

Comment: Well you can't have a second derivative without having a first derivative, right?

Comment: Right, and maybe the first derivative is defined nowhere. Recall that L'Hospital's rule for infinite limits is that the derivative is defined for all $x$ given some sufficiently large $N$ so that $x > N$.

Comment: Look, if $f^{(n)}$ exists on $(a,\infty)$ then so does $f^{(n-1)}$, hence so does $f^{(n-2)}$ etc

Comment: Oh, I see. So we can be sure that the lower derivatives exist for some sufficiently large $N$.

Comment: This is the simpler and correct version of what OP is trying to do in his question. +1